# iterate trough a forms in dictionary passed from view to html in python with jinja

Tags: python, html, django

I would appreciate your help in the below problem:

I need to use 3 different models in a python app which I want the user to populate from a HTML form. I want to use model forms and I pass all the three different form in one dictionary (see my views.py):

```
def new_sales_trip(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        Restaurant_Form = RestaurantForm(request.POST)
        SalesEvent_Form = SalesEventForm(request.POST)
        NextAction_Form = NextActionForm(request.POST)


        if Restaurant_Form.is_valid() and SalesEvent_Form.is_valid() and NextAction_Form.is_valid():
            Restaurants = Restaurant_Form.save()
            SalesEvents = SalesEvent_Form.save(False)
            NextActions = NextAction_Form.save(False)

            SalesEvents.restaurants = Restaurants
            SalesEvents.save()

            NextActions.restaurants = Restaurants
            NextActions.save()

            return redirect('/')

        else:
            allforms = {
                'Restaurant_Form': Restaurant_Form,
                'SalesEvent_Form': SalesEvent_Form,
                'NextAction_Form': NextAction_Form,
            }

            return render(request, 'sales/SalesTrip_form.html', allforms)

    else:
        Restaurant_Form = RestaurantForm()
        SalesEvent_Form = SalesEventForm()
        NextAction_Form = NextActionForm()

        c = {}
        c.update(csrf(request))

        allforms = {
            'Restaurant_Form': Restaurant_Form,
            'SalesEvent_Form': SalesEvent_Form,
            'NextAction_Form': NextAction_Form,
        }

        return render(request, 'sales/SalesTrip_form.html', allforms)
```

So far it works - however I don't know how to use this dictionary to iterate trough in my template so I shouldn't reference all the form by name separatelly. I try to to do something like this:

```
    {% for key, value in allforms.items %}
     {% for field in value %}
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10"> <!--this gonna be only displayed if there is an error in it-->
                <span class="text-danger small">{{ field.errors }}</span>
            </div>
            <label class="control-label col-sm-2">{{ field.label_tag }}</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10"> <!--this gonna be displayed if there is no error -->
                {{ field }}
            </div>
        </div>
   {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Unforunatelly it is not rendering anything but a blank page. If I try the .items() property than it says:

> Could not parse the remainder: '()' from 'allforms.items()'

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add `()` to the end of `items`:

e.g.,

```
 {% for key, value in allforms.items() %}
 {% for field in value %}
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10"> <!--this gonna be only displayed if there is an error in it-->
            <span class="text-danger small">{{ field.errors }}</span>
        </div>
        <label class="control-label col-sm-2">{{ field.label_tag }}</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10"> <!--this gonna be displayed if there is no error -->
            {{ field }}
        </div>
    </div>
```

{% endfor %}
{% endfor %}

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Unfortunatelly it didn't work, I get the error: Could not parse the remainder: '()' from 'allforms.items()'

Comment: Any other idea what would be the solution here?